# Compare two pg_dump results

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, pg-dump

I've got two postgresql databases with simillar but not identical schemas. I want to compare those schemas in order to add missing columns and indices.

So far I've collected the schemas using `pg_dump -s`. But some columns appear in tables in different order, therefore I can't just use `diff` to spot the difference.

Can I somehow alphabetically sort columns in `pg_dump`?

Comment: No you can't. Search on 'database schema diff tools' for your options.